# Get single click event in selection mode with Plotly, with touch device

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, plotly, touch, plotly.js

With the following Plotly.js code, I receive event data when we select a rectangular zone (drag and drop) **and** also when we click on a single point: `plotly_selected` and `plotly_click` events are triggered. This works.

When we do the same with a touch device (can be emulated in Chrome with Developer Tools <kbd>F12</kbd> and "Toggle device toolbar" <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+M</kbd>):

- selection works and triggers a `plotly_selected` event
- single click doesn't work: `plotly_selected` event is triggered **but with no coordinate data**, and **no `plotly_click` is triggered**

**Question: how to have coordinates on a single click in `select` mode with a touch device?**

I tried `clickmode: "select"` or `"event"` or `"event+select"` but the problem is the same.

[Live demo](https://gget.it/dsb3/clickmode.html)

Strangely, the following code hangs the browser when run from SO snippet, but it is runnable from a HTML file, thus the live demo link.

```js
const z = Array.from({length: 50}, () => Array.from({length: 50}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)));
const data = [{type: 'heatmap', z: z}];
const layout = {'yaxis': {'scaleanchor': 'x'}, 'dragmode': 'select'}
const config = { modeBarButtons: [["select2d"]] };
Plotly.newPlot('plot', data, layout, config);
document.querySelector("#plot").on("plotly_click", (e) => { 
    console.log("plotly_click", e); 
});
document.querySelector("#plot").on("plotly_selected", (e) => { 
    console.log("plotly_selected", e); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.25.0.min.js"></script>
<div id="plot"></div>
```

Comment: I opened an issue here: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/6721. @EricLavault would you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add support for touch events to your page. There is a library that can help you do this, below is the link. Have used this in the past works great.
[hammer.js](https://hammerjs.github.io/)

Also below is the snippet that will help you handle the click (tap) on touch device. And a [JSFiddle Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3ko8tbj4/)

```js
const z = Array.from({length: 50}, () => Array.from({length: 50}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)));
const data = [{type: 'heatmap', z: z}];
const layout = {'yaxis': {'scaleanchor': 'x'}, 'dragmode': 'select'}
const config = { modeBarButtons: [["select2d"]] };
Plotly.newPlot('plot', data, layout, config);
var plot = document.getElementById('plot');
plot.on("plotly_click", (e) => { 
    console.log("plotly_click", e); 
});
plot.on("plotly_selected", (e) => { 
    console.log("plotly_selected", e); 
});
//Add support to handle touch screen events on plot
var plotTouch = new Hammer(plot);
plotTouch.on('tap', function(e) {
    console.log("plotly_tap",e);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.25.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://hammerjs.github.io/dist/hammer.min.js"></script>
<div id="plot"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, this doesn't give access to the information in the Plotly plot's coordinates. When the `plotly_click` event is triggered (with a real mouse click), we have access to `points: Array(1)`, which gives the click position *in Plotly plot's coordinate*. Here with your solution we have a `tap` event, but disconnected to the plot coordinate system.